# ystockquote data import into numpy array, IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Having issues indexing a numpy array after I import stock quotes from ystockquote:

```
import numpy as np
import ystockquote as ysq
startdate = "2016-04-06"
enddate = "2016-04-07"

q = np.array(ysq.get_historical_prices("AAPL", startdate, enddate)) 

print(q)

{'2016-04-07': {'Close': '108.540001', 'Volume': '30881000', 'Adj Close': '108.540001', 'High': '110.419998', 'Low': '108.120003', 'Open': '109.949997'}, '2016-04-06': {'Close': '110.959999', 'Volume': '26047800', 'Adj Close': '110.959999', 'High': '110.980003', 'Low': '109.199997', 'Open': '110.230003'}}



  q[0,0]

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-105-ad764cdee54e>", line 1, in <module>
    q[0,0]

IndexError: too many indices for array

    q[0,:]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-106-069fcfa0a0f6>", line 1, in <module>
    q[0,:]

IndexError: too many indices for array


    q[:,0]

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-107-782637b90296>", line 1, in <module>
    q[:,0]

IndexError: too many indices for array

    q.shape

Out[108]: ()
```

It seems that the array has no dimensions. Can anybody explain what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

You are basically trying to put a dict in an array which makes no real sense, maybe items will be closer to what you want:

```
d = {'2016-04-07': {'Close': '108.540001', 'Volume': '30881000', 'Adj Close': '108.540001', 'High': '110.419998', 'Low': '108.120003', 'Open': '109.949997'}, '2016-04-06': {'Close': '110.959999', 'Volume': '26047800', 'Adj Close': '110.959999', 'High': '110.980003', 'Low': '109.199997', 'Open': '110.230003'}}


q = np.array(list(d.items()))
print(q)
print q[0]
print(q.size)
```

Which gives you:

```
[['2016-04-07'
  {'High': '110.419998', 'Adj Close': '108.540001', 'Volume': '30881000', 'Low': '108.120003', 'Close': '108.540001', 'Open': '109.949997'}]
 ['2016-04-06'
  {'High': '110.980003', 'Adj Close': '110.959999', 'Volume': '26047800', 'Low': '109.199997', 'Close': '110.959999', 'Open': '110.230003'}]]
['2016-04-07'
 {'High': '110.419998', 'Adj Close': '108.540001', 'Volume': '30881000', 'Low': '108.120003', 'Close': '108.540001', 'Open': '109.949997'}]
4
```

But I am not sure that is much more useful than just using the dict itself.

Comment: Thanks Padraic. I'm still very new to Python. The goal is to the data into a numpy array where each row represents the data (i.e. 6 data points) for a date.
I still get the indexing error based on your example when calling
print (q[0])

Maybe a version issue? I'm in Spyder 2.3.8 using IPython (Python 3.5)

Comment: @Thor, ah ok, we need to call `list(d.items())` for python 3